# Edit, Delete and Insert in a programmatically created GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, edit, insert-update

So I'm facing a problem. In fact i have created a databound GridView programmatically. The problem is I want to be interactive (update , delete, insert and all that drill) but only using c# since i have created it programmatically.
Here is the code that'ive created with the GridView

```
 GridView grid = new GridView();
            //CSS
            grid.CssClass = "grid";
            grid.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            grid.ShowFooter = true;
            grid.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "gridAltRow";
            grid.RowStyle.CssClass = "gridRow";
            grid.FooterStyle.CssClass = "gridFooterRow";
            grid.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
            grid.RowCommand




            //End Css

            grid.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;            

            grid.DataSource = element.GetElementByRubric(testrub.ID);

            panel.Controls.Add(grid);
            grid.DataBind();

            TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(panel);
```

as you can see i added an edit button but it does nothing of course. Does anyone have any suggestions ??

thx

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the function for updating the database in onrowupdating event of the gridview to make the edit link work.

Comment: I have a function that updates dataBase but it's the event that I don't know how to write it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you generating a grid in code? This is highly unusual.

It may or may not be possible but why are you avoiding just writing the grid directly to the ASPX file?

Comment: as you can see i'm creating the gridview programmatically because each tab panel  has its own gridview. I couldn't create a gridView in aspx because it seems to appear only in the last tabPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a handler for the `OnRowEditing` event. Something similar to

```
grid.RowEditing+=new GridViewEditEventHandler(grid_RowEditing_RowEditing);
```

to attach the event handler and then an event handler like below. In this case the `sender` will be the dynamically created GridView.

```
protected void grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
   // Then call your databinding method here to update the grid.
}
```

This would also be the same method you would use to add handlers for the delete and insert events also.

Comment: i can't do that because "grid" is a local variable. that code generates an error for me because grid is not a global variable in the class

Comment: Which line? You need to add the eventhandler just before you add the grid to the Panel; `grid` is in scope there.

Comment: So I added this code 
   <pre> grid.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
     grid.RowEditing+=new GridViewEditEventHandler(grid_RowEditing); 
     protected void grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            Element elt = new Element();
            GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
            
        }
<code>

I don't know where to go frome here like how to get the selected row? or how to apply changes

please help

Comment: `e.NewEditIndex` gets the index for the current row that the edit command was fired for. Setting the `EditIndex` of the grid to this basically just tells it to show the edit template for that specific row index. You then need to handle the `RowUpdating` event to update the details in the database to whatever they entered. Does the GridView have to be generated dynamically as this seems to be creating a lot of extra work and confusion.

Comment: i have tried to use a gridview the usual way from the toobox and all and tried to bind it to an object data source but that didn't work for me because my select method need a define parameter from control, cookie, session, RouteData. In ly case i tried binding it to the tabPanels but that can't be done since the tabcontainer does not even show in the list of controls and in addition to that the gridview only show in the last TabPanel so I guess either the Hard way or a completely other way . ans i'm completely stuck